# Как отфильтровать данные в сервисе Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

Добрый вечер. Необходимо сделать перевод статей 
Есть данные

```
     [{
"name": {    
      "en": "name-english",
      "de" : "name-deutch"
        }, 
"title": {
      "en": "english title",
      "de": "deutch title"
        } 
      }]
```

Есть сервис, который забирает эти данные.

```
app.factory('DataJson', ['$resource','$translate',  function($resource,         $translate) {
   var article = $resource('translate.json');
     var CurrentLanguage = $translate.use() || $translate.storage().get($translate.storageKey()) || $translate.preferredLanguage();
     var data = article;
        return data
    }
]);
```

Как сделать, чтобы из данных дергался только определенный язык? И выдавался уже обычным путем

```
     <div ng-repeat="vm in data">
      <p>Name - {{vm.name}}</p>
      <p>Title- {{vm.title }}</p>
     </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/w9QQDwB2oGcEZLuACYyD?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

#### Вариант 1

Самый простой вариант, когда необходимо изменить только представление (View)

**index.html**

```
<p>Name - {{vm.name[CurrentLanguage()] }}</p>
<p>Title- {{vm.title[CurrentLanguage()] }}</p>
```

#### Вариант 2

Я не большой знаток философии Углового, но, похоже, тут дело касется модели (Model), поэтому попробуйте что-то вроде этого:

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$translate',
    '$scope',
    'DataJson',
    function($translate, $scope, DataJson) {
      $scope.curLang = $translate.preferredLanguage();
      $scope.CurrentLanguage = function() {
        var CurrentLanguage = $translate.use() || $translate.storage().get($translate.storageKey()) || $translate.preferredLanguage();
        return CurrentLanguage;
      };
      // Switch language
      $scope.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey).then(function(e) {
          $scope.curLang = e
        });
      };
      // Get data from base
      $scope.data = DataJson.query();
    }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<h3>Get {{curLang}} language</h3>  
<div ng-repeat="vm in data">
<p>Name - {{vm.name[curLang] }}</p>
<p>Title- {{vm.title[curLang] }}</p>
```

В данном примере используется переменная `curLang` для хранения текущего состояния контроллера.

#### Вариант 3

Не совсем понял логику вашего приложения, но может быть значение языка лучше хранить в переменных приложения?